# Responsive menu won't shift between single and 3-column

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I'm trying to code a simple menu that will shift between a single column on the left edge of the screen to a three-column menu at the top of the screen. So far, shifting the position of the menu is working out fine, but trying to get the single column to split into three columns that all sit horizontally next to each other is another matter. So far, my code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
        <div id="logo">
        <ul>
        <li><center><img src="assets/img/logo.png"></center></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="nav1">
        <ul><center>
        <li><img src="assets/img/home.png"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/gallery.png"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/sketch.png"></li>
        </center></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="nav2">
        <ul><center>
        <li><img src="assets/img/about.png"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/contact.png"></li>
        <li><img src="assets/img/store.png"></li>
        </center></ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    display: inline;
    width: 20
    float: left;
}

#nav1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 20%;
}

#nav2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an image or video of the effect you’re trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm completely self-taught and trying to cobble together what I can learn from internet articles, so I'm not surprised I've picked up bad habits. Thanks for the info, I'll do some tweaking!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/a0edegg5/


because you set width of `#nav1` element is 40% and `#nav2` is also 40% and '#logo' is 20% and you also set margin-left property of `#nav1` and `#nav2`(20% and 40%). it's all 160%. so that's the reason why all element can't be the same line(it's more than 100%).


anyways you shouldn't use tag `<center>` anymore and you should use `nav` instead of `div`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The #nav elements are positioned correctly now, but still aren't lining up vertically the way they should. I'll keep tweaking. What should I use instead of <center>?

Comment: @slimmeroo What is mean by "lining up vertically"? could you explain more?
if you want to align the element to center,it depends on what type of element. there're 2 type-block and inline(you can set it by using 'display' property).if it's block,you should use 'margin:0 auto' and if it's inline,you should use 'text-align:center'. anyways there're many ways to align the element to center using css. try to find in the internet or some books :)